# Were the Gestapo & SS voluntary organisations?

Tags: world-war-two

In a book that I am reading about the Nuremberg Trials I came across the following:

> Justice Jackson intended to 'prove the criminal character of several voluntary organisations that played a cruel and controlling part in subjugating Germany and then her neighbours, such as the SS & Gestapo.

Q. In my laymans knowledge of history I had understood the Gestapo to be the secret police and hence not voluntary. In what way were they voluntary, and in what way were they not? Ditto for the SS.

Comment: Do you think that Gestapo officers and members of the SS were volunteers or conscripts?

Comment: @sempaiscuba: I've no idea. That's why I'm asking the question! My personal feeling is that the hard-core would be volunteers. But going by that extract above it looks like most, if not all were. Perhaps there was an element of compulsion too. After all, I wouldn't have thought the Nazis weren't above compelling people to do their will.

Comment: @semipaiscuba: After all, the Nazis somehow managed to seize power without violating the rules and laws of the constitution. They were a sneaky lot.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Oh, they very much violated the constitution...

Comment: @semipaiscuba: I'd also question what Judge Jackson means by voluntary here too. He might simply mean that they weren't paid, or that they weren't officially recognised.

Comment: @DevSolar: They seized power by democratic means. It was fascism with a democratic face.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Compare the [German federal election in November 1932](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_federal_election,_November_1932) with the [German federal election in March 1933](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_federal_election,_March_1933) -- and even there the NSDAP did not win a majority. Hitler's far-reaching powers were [seized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_rise_to_power#Chancellor_to_dictator), not democratically voted for. (Democratic votes are free, secret, equal, and general, with basic rights of freedom of opinion and a free press...)

Comment: @MoziburUllah: The [Socialist Unity Party of Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_Unity_Party_of_Germany) was also "democratically elected"... there's a difference between having held "a vote", and being democratically legitimized...

Comment: @DevSolar: Hitler didn't march on Berlin like Mussolini did. He used every possible democratic lever at hand to gain power.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Putting the Reichstag in a building filled and surrounded by your thugs and demanding the [Enabling Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling_Act_of_1933) from them isn't a *democratic* lever in my book, for example. There is so much between lawful democracy and "marching on the capital" that we shouldn't take lightly, *especially* with an eye on the Erdogans, Putins and Trumps of today...

Comment: @DevSolar: I know all about that. The whole regime was criminal. He lied, he used propaganda, he used violence. Nevertheless that doesn't alter the fact that Hitler used all available democratic means at his disposal to gain legitimacy and power.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86135/discussion-between-devsolar-and-mozibur-ullah).

Comment: @DevSolar: Some other day, I'm busy right now.

Comment: @MoziburUllah The recruitment practices for the [SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel), [Waffen SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts#Recruitment_and_conscription), and [Gestapo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestapo) are explained on their respective Wikipedia pages.

Comment: @MoziburUllah As to Justice Jackson's intentions, since you haven't provided a source for the quote in the question I can't comment on whether those were his words or the author's.

Comment: Why would you assume the secret police were not voluntary?  The secret police by definition are going to be filled with not just volunteers but zealots.  Please document your assumption.

Comment: You need more reasoning for the Q ("hence"?) & perhaps this: [The Party formations, including the Leadership Corps of the Party, the SD, the SS, the SA, and the infamous Secret State Police, or Gestapo,-all these stand accused before you as criminal organizations; organizations which, as we will prove from their own documents, were recruited only from recklessly devoted Nazis, ready in conviction and temperament to do the most violent of deeds to advance the common program.](https://www.roberthjackson.org/speech-and-writing/opening-statement-before-the-international-military-tribunal/)

Answer (score 13):

**Gestapo**

Prior to 1933, there was the [Prussian Secret Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_Secret_Police), "Abteilung I A". As such, it was a police unit, i.e. working there was very much voluntary.

In 1933, the Prussian Secret Police was *renamed* "Geheime Staatspolizei" (Secret State Police), abbreviated Gestapo. (Which made all the staff of the Prussian Secret Police -- volunteers -- now "Gestapo members".)

Legal restrictions on their actions were removed step by step, and the organization eventually separated from the police apparatus and placed under direct control of Göring (Secretary of the Interior) and later Himmler (Chief of German Police and Reichsführer of the SS) .

At no point did the Gestapo *press* people into working there. I can imagine that *quitting* service with the Gestapo, or turning down a transfer, could raise some eyebrows. But it **was a voluntary organization** (as far as anything under totalitarian rule can be voluntary).

**Schutzstaffel (SS)**

The beginnings of the [Schutzstaffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel) in 1925 were as personal bodyguards and thugs to Adolf Hitler (very much voluntary). The organization grew and became more militarized, but well into the times of the [Waffen-SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS) it remained **a voluntary organization**.

Only from 1943 onward (or possibly as early as [February 1942](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts#Recruitment_and_conscription)) did the Waffen-SS **draft** men into service.

Comment: One [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts#Recruitment_and_conscription) indicates Waffen-SS conscription began as early as February 1942. This only applied to the Waffen-SS though. The _[Allgemeine SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allgemeine_SS)_ (General SS) and _[SS-Totenkopfverbände (SS-TV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Totenkopfverb%C3%A4nde)_ remained voluntary, but towards the end of the war the _SS-Totenkopfverbände_ in the camps were supplemented (and even replaced) with _SS-Mannschaft_ (Auxilliary-SS) which may have been drafted.

Comment: One more comment - the Getsapo was created by Göring in 1933, but in April 1934 it came under the control of Himmler, and stayed there for the rest of the Third Reich's miserable existence (Himmler was appointed Chief of German Police in 1936 too). From 1939 on Himmler put the Gestapo under the control of the RSHA under Heydrich (all still under Himmler's authority) and the organization then essentially became connected to the SS _Sicherheitsdienst_ (SD) (Security Service). Göring was out of the picture by '34 and it became Himmler's show entirely.

Comment: @KerryL: Edited that in as well.

Comment: You had my +1 even before the edits - just wanted to help with a couple of clarifications :-)